# JIT Optimization: Why Is It Slow and How Can I Improve It?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, jit

I have been looking into method inlining with JIT and landed on [this article by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx).  I took his code a little further, and it seems that while there are only a few call stacks when the code runs in Release mode, at actually does seem to run as if those extra frames still exist within the compiled code (even if they do not report as such).

To start, I have put the code up here if you want to jump in and run it:
https://github.com/Mike-EEE/StackOverflow.Performance

I have tried this on .NET 4.7.1, .NET Core 2.0, and even the new [.NET Core 2.1 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/11/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-2/) that was recently announced.  All feature the same results.

What I have done is created a simple command that emits a message, and then create a subsequent multi-decorated command that wraps this simple command several times over.  In the code as published, this decoration is done 10 times, resulting in a nested command with 10 levels (or 11 if you count the origin simple command).

Both of these commands used in test use an empty delegate to emit a message, as using a `Console.WriteLine` during a performance test gets rather ugly.

Before I run the tests, I do create a decorated command that uses the same code as the tested code, but instead of an empty delegate, use a `Console.WriteLine` to verify the stack trace within the current execution environment.

In Debug, this stack trace looks like the following:

```
   at StackOverflow.Performance.EmitMessage.Emit(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.EmitMessage.MethodC(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.EmitMessage.MethodB(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.EmitMessage.MethodA(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.EmitMessage.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.DecoratedCommand.Execute(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.Program.Main()
```

In Release, it looks like this:

```
   at StackOverflow.Performance.EmitMessage.Emit(String message)
   at StackOverflow.Performance.Program.Main()
```

To this point, everything looks awesome and exactly how I would expect.  However, I then execute these two commands via [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to see what the results are in a performance setting.  These results do seem to suggest that the decorated command's call chain is executed in full, even though the emitted stack trace suggests that no such call chain exists:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.14, OS=Windows 10.0.16299.371 (1709/FallCreatorsUpdate/Redstone3)
Intel Core i7-4820K CPU 3.70GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=2.1.300-preview2-008533
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.0.7 (CoreCLR 4.6.26328.01, CoreFX 4.6.26403.03), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.0.7 (CoreCLR 4.6.26328.01, CoreFX 4.6.26403.03), 64bit RyuJIT


    Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
---------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
    Direct |  3.581 ns | 0.0759 ns | 0.0710 ns |
 Decorated | 44.646 ns | 0.7701 ns | 0.7203 ns |
```

So, it would seem that more than 2 frames are being executed here, and that has led me to posting this question here on StackOverflow.  I do have several questions around this:

1. Is there something fundamentally inaccurate with my code?  This would be *incredibly* embarrassing but I want to weed out the obvious, first. :)
2. If my code and results are indeed accurate, then: Is this a known issue? And/or is this executing as designed?
3. My assumption here is this is the Tail-call Optimization that is being employed.  Could it be that the method inlining is also taking place here?  I guess my basic question here is: what *exactly* is being optimized with such unexpectedly un-optimized results?
4. **Most importantly**: Is there anyway to ensure and achieve the optimized results that I am looking for?  Any sort of magic to pass through to the root delegate would be valuable here.  It does seem that the root delegate is *resolved* correctly, just not *invoked* correctly.

For the sake of completeness, here is all the code to run this sample:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Writes out the stack trace from a decorated command:
        Decorate.Get(new EmitMessage(Console.WriteLine))
                .Execute(null);

        BenchmarkRunner.Run<Program>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    readonly ICommand _direct, _decorated;
    readonly string _message;

    public Program() : this(new EmitMessage()) {}

    public Program(ICommand direct) : this(direct, Decorate.Get(direct), "Hello World!") {}

    public Program(ICommand direct, ICommand decorated, string message)
    {
        _direct    = direct;
        _decorated = decorated;
        _message = message;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Direct()
    {
        _direct.Execute(_message);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Decorated()
    {
        _decorated.Execute(_message);
    }
}

static class Decorate
{
    public static ICommand Get(ICommand parameter)
        => Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                     .Aggregate(parameter, (command, _) => new DecoratedCommand(command));
}

sealed class DecoratedCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly ICommand _command;

    public DecoratedCommand(ICommand command) => _command = command;

    public void Execute(string message)
    {
        _command.Execute(message);
    }
}

sealed class EmitMessage : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<string> _emit;

    public EmitMessage() : this(_ => {}) {}

    public EmitMessage(Action<string> emit) => _emit = emit;

    public void Execute(string message)
    {
        MethodA(message);
    }

    void MethodA(string message)
    {
        MethodB(message);
    }

    void MethodB(string message)
    {
        MethodC(message);
    }

    void MethodC(string message)
    {
        Emit(message);
    }

    void Emit(string message)
    {
        _emit(message ?? new StackTrace().ToString());
    }
}

public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute(string message);
}
```

Thank you in advance for any insight/assistance that you can provide!

Comment: JIT takes time to compile the code, so the first-time through may be slow. You should run your code in more than one loop and average out the times.

Comment: That's a good point, @RonBeyer.  BenchmarkDotNet is supposed to handle that automatically for you in its test runs, from what I understand.  Nonetheless I did try running a few precursory executions on the commands before they get tested and ended up with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shamelessly copying Stephen Toub's work from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/18/performance-improvements-in-net-core-2-1/?replytocom=512075)

> I just looked at the disassembly for DecoratedCommandUsing a checked build of coreclr and running with `setCOMPlus_JitDisasm=Execute` see [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/viewing-jit-dumps.md). Indeed it's using tail calls:
>
> > ; Assembly listing for method `DecoratedCommand:Execute(ref)`:this
>
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for X64 CPU with AVX
>
> ; optimized code
>
> ; rsp based frame
>
> ; fully interruptible
>
> ; Final local variable assignments
>
> ; V00 this [V00,T00] ( 3, 3 ) ref -> rcx this class-hnd
>
> ; V01 arg1 [V01,T01] ( 3, 3 ) ref -> rdx class-hnd
>
> ;# V02 OutArgs [V02 ] ( 1, 1 ) lclBlk ( 0) [rsp+0x00]
>
> ; Lcl frame size = 0
>
> G_M223_IG01:
>
> G_M223_IG02:
>
> 488B4908 mov rcx, gword ptr [rcx+8]
>
> 49BB48007733FD7F0000 mov r11, 0x7FFD33770048
>
> 488B05934FE5FF mov rax, qword ptr [(reloc)]
>
> 3909 cmp dword ptr [rcx], ecx
>
> G_M223_IG03:
>
> 48FFE0 rex.jmp rax

Comment: FWIW @Dwayne that downvote was not by me, but welcome to StackOverflow. ;)  As you see in that thread I am still unclear how the optimization takes place, and am further unclear on why the method isn't inlined since it seems to be able to resolve it as it does.  Additionally, I am looking for an answer that describes how to reduce the overhead.

Comment: hah, thanks. I'm not overmuch worried about it, just thought I'd stumbled across something worthwhile.  Have you looked at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/275)? I'm not certain how you'd make the aggregate function 'semantically identical' though.

Comment: Yeah that's interesting.  I am sort of starting to get the feeling that this issue will result in a GitHub issue/request, myself.  Unless there is some super magic that has managed to escape my research.  I think Mr. Toub would have mentioned something, however.  Or my question got lost in the mix.  Oh well.  FWIW I will upvote your answer as it is the closest approximation I have seen of such and is properly -- and honestly! -- referenced.  Also, downvoters should be posting a reason for their down votes. :P

Comment: FWIW, that predicted GitHub issue/request has emerged, LOL.  You can find that here if you wish to follow along: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1784#issuecomment-392554011

Comment: Congratulations @Dwayne your shamelessness has paid off.  In addition to the issue above, another one has been provided there at the GitHub repo: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6737  So it would seem that these are known limitations that are captured by the team there and will hopefully be addressed in a future version, perhaps by tiered JITing.  This, in addition to your (or rather, _Stephen_'s :)) answer/efforts has given me enough context and information to be confident in understanding this problem for now  and, hopefully, a future resolution for the remaining concerns.

Comment: @Mike-E thanks for your question and your links! I use the same pattern (and many others, as I commented on #6737) that involve lots of delegates; they are used in a way that should increase performance, but in the end missing inling hinders the benefits.